# Dependency injection constructor with parameters: Component in `RouteConfig` initial error

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have the `app.component.ts` like this:

```
import { RouteConfig, Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/meter', name: 'Meter', component: Meter
  }
])
```

and `app.tpl.html` like this:

```
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

The `Meter` component is like this:

```
import { Device } from './device.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'meter',
  providers: [Device],
  template: require('./meter.tpl.html')
})
export class Meter {
  constructor(
    public devices: Device
  ) {

  }
}
```

The `Device` model is like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Device {    
  constructor(
    public deviceSerialNr: string
  ) {
      console.log('Device created');
  }
}
```

When I run the app, I get the error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for String!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
```

But if I move the attribute `public xx: XXX` from `constructor` parameter to class root, it will be ok.

**---------------UPDATE--------------**

I should not inject Device class as a parameter in the angular component constructor. Just remove @Injectable from Device class and remove public device decalre from constructor of Meter.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here,

```
@Injectable()
export class Device {    
  constructor(
    public deviceSerialNr: string  <------problem area
  ) {
      console.log('Device created');
  }
}
```

instead you should write,

```
@Injectable()
    export class Device {   
     public deviceSerialNr: string;   <------look here
      constructor() {
          console.log('Device created');
      }
  }
```

OR

```
@Injectable()
    export class Device {     
      constructor() {
          this.deviceSerialNr="someValue";     <------look here
          console.log('Device created');
      }
}
```